# Org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java

Помогите решить проблемму:

Отправляю запрос серверу, он возвращает null, соответственно код мне не надо выполнять,   а он все равно выполняется вызывая исключение "org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray"

Первый блок if вообще игнорируется, даже если написать так:

```
if(1>1)

if(result != null){... Так тоже нет

if(!result.equals("null")){

        try{
            final JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

               for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++) 
                  {
                     JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                     extId = json_data.getString("id");
                  }
          }catch(JSONException e1){
                     Log.d(tag, e1.toString());
            }

    }
```

Comment: @Eser, я мимо проходил и в java не разбираюсь, но вы точно не путаете null и "null"?

Comment: Первый блок if вообще игнорируется, даже если написать так: if(1>1)

Comment: @Eser, Жизнь-боль. Видимо Вы попали в немилость богу-машине и он сломал базовые конструкции языка.

Answer (score 1):

Перед тем как получить ответ, проинициализируй result = "" и проверяй не только на "null", но и на пустую строку

```
if(!(result.equals(""))&&!result.equals("null"))
```

Comment: Первый блок if вообще игнорируется, даже если написать так: if(1>1)

Comment: посмотри чему result равен

Comment: Eclipse тупил